# If each one of array contains one string push to another array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a very basic question about PHP, I could not solve it with other answers in stackoverflow.

I have an array like :

```
[0] => this one i need 1
[1] => this one i need 2
[2] => not need this one
```

so, I want to check for every one, if it contains 'this one i need', then put that into another array

So we must have this array at least :

```
[0] => this one i need 1
[1] => this one i need 2
```

I tried to do it like this but it returned Empty array :

```
foreach($one as $value) {
   if(in_array("my name",$value)) $ok[] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify you want to loop through all elements of the array, and if an element = 'XYZ' add to another array?

Comment: @buzzlightyear yeah, IF **contains** one string add to another array. Not equal to !

Comment: Based on your code, `$value` should be array since you are using it as an array parameter in `in_array()` function, but based on `foreach()`, it should not be an array. So which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<?php

$one = array();

$one[0] = "this one i need 1";
$one[1] = "this one i need 2";
$one[2] = "not need this one";

$ok = array();
$find_str = "this one i need";
foreach($one as $value) {
       if(strpos($value, $find_str) !==false) 
       {
         $ok[] = $value;
       }  
    }


    print_r($ok);
?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => this one i need 1
    [1] => this one i need 2
)
```

**[Demo](https://eval.in/181315)**

**UPDATE 2 :**

as OP's `$value` is an array

```
$ok = array();
$find_str = "this one i need";
foreach($one as $value) {
   foreach($value as $val){
       if(strpos($val, $find_str) !==false) 
       {
         $ok[] = $value;
       }  
    }
 }   

    print_r($ok);
```

Comment: Error : 
Warning:  strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: is `$value` is your array? please put your input array here

Comment: @Pafo try update 2 if `$value` is your array and this have values shown in question.

Comment: Tnx, i tried update two, i have very very big list, every array contains all of values :D

Comment: I am trying with all answers but i still giving that error !

Comment: I got where is problem, the main array, is one value of another array, how to relode all values to one array? its like this : `
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (...`

Answer (score 1):

The built-in [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function is intended precisely for this purpose

```
$needle = 'XYZ';
$newArray = array_filter(
    $originalArray,
    function ($value) use ($needle) {
        return (strpos($value, $needle) !== false);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_filter` is the perfect tool to delete unwanted elements based on values

```
$one[0] = "this one i need 1";
$one[1] = "this one i need 2";
$one[2] = "not need this one";

$wanted_string = 'this one i need';

$array_out = array_filter($one, function($var) use($wanted_string) {
            return strpos($var, $wanted_string) !== false;
});

// array(2) { [0]=> string(17) "this one i need 1" [1]=> string(17) "this one i need 2" }
```